# How to use partial text instead of exact in selector?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I've written a script in python to collect movie names and its genre from a torrent site. As `BeautifulSoup` doesn't support pseudo selectors, I found a technique to overcome that. The only problem I'm facing at this moment is that to get the results THE TEXT WITHIN INVERTED COMMA in the below script has to be exact. Is there any way I can use something similar to `:contains` property as in partial match so that even if the text in my query contains the partial words I will still parse the `Genre` i'm after. [expected to use `Gen` or `nre:` or `enr` instead of `Genre:` in the script]

Here is the script:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://www.yify-torrent.org/search/1080p/").text,"lxml")
for title in soup.select("div.mv"):
    names = title.select("h3 a")[0].text
    genre = ' '.join([item.next_sibling for item in title.select(".mdif li b") if item.text=="Genre:"])
    print(names, genre)
```

Result:

```
Swelter (2014) 1080p Action
Larry Crowne (2011) 1080p Comedy
Terminal Island (1973) 1080p Action
Heart of Midnight (1988) 1080p Drama
The Lift (1983) 1080p Fantasy
```

Comment: I don't understand your question; however, I would note that Scrapy supports pseudo-elements, etc: see https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html.

Comment: Sometimes the text i used above is long enough to use like this, that is why I wanted to go for partial match other than using the exact text. I've used scrapy and lxml as well. However I wanted to know how it can be used in BeautifulSoup as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [`in`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/membership_operators_example.htm) operator to check whether string contains substring:

```
genre = ' '.join([item.next_sibling for item in title.select(".mdif li b") if "Genre:" in item.text])
```

You can use `if "Genre:" in item.text` as well as `if "nre:" in item.text`, `if "Gen" in item.text`, etc...